# Can I hook when a weakly-referenced object (of arbitrary type) is freed?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, weak-references

I'm writing a container class in Swift, which works like as `java.util.WeakHashMap` in Java. My current implementation is here.

```
class WeakRefMap<Key: Hashable, Value: AnyObject> {

    private var mapping = [Key: WeakBox<Value>]()

    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get { return mapping[key]?.raw }
        set {
            if let o = newValue {
                mapping[key] = WeakBox(o)
            }
            else {
                mapping.removeValueForKey(key)
            }
        }
    }

    var count: Int { return mapping.count }
}

class WeakBox<E: AnyObject> {
    weak var raw: E!
    init(  _ raw: E) { self.raw = raw }
}
```

In this implementation, holded objects in the container are weakly-referenced via `WeakBox`, so holding values never prevents the objects from being released when not needed anymore.

But clearly there is a problem in this code; The entries remains even after the object of its entry is freed.

To solve this problem, I need to hook just before a holded object is released, and remove its (corresponding) entry. I know a solution only for `NSObject`, but it's not applicable to `AnyObject`.

Could anyone help me? Thanks. (^_^)

Comment: Try using the `deinit` method - see the [Apple Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html).

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497928/dealloc-in-swift

Comment: Thanks. But that's not what I meant. The container class I made is a generic class, so it needs to work for all the subtypes of `AnyObject` as its `Value`. The `deinit` approach is applicable only when type is decidable.

Comment: It seems that there is no way for Swift classes, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317332/know-when-a-weak-var-becomes-nil-in-swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sad to say, `didSet` or `willSet` observer doesn't get called when `weak var raw` property value is deallocated.

So, you have to use `objc_setAssociatedObject` in this case:

```
// helper class to notify deallocation
class DeallocWatcher {
    let notify:()->Void
    init(_ notify:()->Void) { self.notify = notify }
    deinit { notify() }
}

class WeakRefMap<Key: Hashable, Value: AnyObject> {

    private var mapping = [Key: WeakBox<Value>]()

    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get { return mapping[key]?.raw }
        set {
            if let o = newValue {
                // Add helper to associated objects.
                // When `o` is deallocated, `watcher` is also deallocated.
                // So, `watcher.deinit()` will get called.
                let watcher = DeallocWatcher { [unowned self] in self.mapping[key] = nil }
                objc_setAssociatedObject(o, unsafeAddressOf(self), watcher, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
                mapping[key] = WeakBox(o)
            }
            else {
                mapping[key] = nil
            }
        }
    }

    var count: Int { return mapping.count }

    deinit {
        // cleanup
        for e in self.mapping.values {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(e.raw, unsafeAddressOf(self), nil, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE: Before Swift 1.2. this solution does not work for arbitrary Swift classes.**

Comment: Does this work for arbitrary Swift classes or only for subclasses of NSObject (for which OP claims to already have a solution) ?

Comment: Ah, it seems, it doesn't work for non-`NSObject` subclasses. :(

Comment: @MartinR It seems, it does work in Xcode 6.3 Beta, but not in Xcode 6.1.1. I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @rintaro san! I've assumed mistakenly that `objc_setAssociatedObject` does not work for `AnyObject`, but now I tested and noticed it works in Swift 1.2. (But not in older versions.)

Answer (score 1):

Previous example has some bugs, for example:

Invalid size of dictionary bug: this example prints "1" instead of "2":

```
let dict = WeakRefMap<String, NSObject>()
autoreleasepool {
    let val = NSObject()
    dict["1"] = val
    dict["2"] = val
    print("dict size: \(dict.count)")
}
```

Fixed WeakRefMap:

```
private class DeallocWatcher<Key: Hashable> {

    let notify:(keys: Set<Key>)->Void

    private var keys = Set<Key>()

    func insertKey(key: Key) {
        keys.insert(key)
    }

    init(_ notify:(keys: Set<Key>)->Void) { self.notify = notify }
    deinit { notify(keys: keys) }
}

public class WeakRefMap<Key: Hashable, Value: AnyObject> {

    private var mapping = [Key: WeakBox<Value>]()

    public init() {}

    public subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get { return mapping[key]?.raw }
        set {
            if let o = newValue {
                // Add helper to associated objects.
                // When `o` is deallocated, `watcher` is also deallocated.
                // So, `watcher.deinit()` will get called.

                if let watcher = objc_getAssociatedObject(o, unsafeAddressOf(self)) as? DeallocWatcher<Key> {

                    watcher.insertKey(key)
                } else {

                    let watcher = DeallocWatcher { [unowned self] (keys: Set<Key>) -> Void in
                        for key in keys {
                            self.mapping[key] = nil
                        }
                    }

                    watcher.insertKey(key)

                    objc_setAssociatedObject(o, unsafeAddressOf(self), watcher, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
                }

                mapping[key] = WeakBox(o)
            } else {
                if let index = mapping.indexForKey(key) {

                    let (_, value) = mapping[index]
                    objc_setAssociatedObject(value.raw, unsafeAddressOf(self), nil, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
                    mapping.removeAtIndex(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public var count: Int { return mapping.count }

    deinit {
        // cleanup
        for e in self.mapping.values {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(e.raw, unsafeAddressOf(self), nil, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```